# How to read a cell from next row and same column in excel in c#/

Tags: c#

```
  for (int rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
   {
       for (int cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Rows.Count; cCnt++)
       {
           if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, cCnt].Value != null)
           {

               comments.Clear();
               value = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, cCnt].Value.ToString();
               content.Add(xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, cCnt].Value.ToString());


             value1=xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt+1, cCnt].Value;
```

Here, in the last line, even if the values is not null, it is always returning a null. Its giving an error like" cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference c#". Can anyone help in resolving this out?

Comment: What makes you think it's not null if it's returning null?

Comment: I have that excel sheet in which value is not null for the case it is returning null.

Comment: Well, that's not always the case. When `rCnt = range.Rows.Count`, then it's likely the cell at `rCnt+1` will be null, no?

Comment: yes but in starting it has rows with values. Why it is giving error at that point?